# Rules for Reducers in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

One of the rules for Reducers in Redux is that we should not return undefined from our reducer (any other return value seems fine including null)

I just wanted to understand the reason behind that. Is it because of how the Redux library is built ?

Answer (score 0):

you cant return undefined from reducers, if it returns undefined then you'll get an error like this one
`Uncaught Error: Reducer returned undefined when handling action`

I got the below line from the redux documentation :

A reducer may be called with undefined as the state value when the application is being initialized. If that happens, we need to provide an initial state value so the rest of the reducer code has something to work with

Comment: But any reason why that is the case...I mean internally speaking?

Comment: if we are getting an error then that must be the way its built and why would anyone want to return undefined , null can be used in place of that. Sry i might be wrong but i think that is one of the reasons for it not returning undefined

Comment: So, when it says, "A reducer may be called with undefined as the state value when the application is being initialized"....what exactly does it mean? From which code ?

Comment: i also think that since redux can be used with other frameworks build on different languages like java which dont have an undefined data type but most support null so that could be one of the reasons

Comment: pls look at this page,  and type undefined in the search tab to search for specific texts they have shown the code there  https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers

Comment: if the reducer has some intital state like this `(state = initialState, action)`. then at the beginning when the application is being initialized the value of this state is undefined and then it gets assigned the value of initial state

Answer (score 0):

This is how the redux library is built. You can check here it's simply checking and throwing error message.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/45111a63d39a0c0fbd8b5417b2ad623718d42d66/src/combineReducers.ts#L78

> A reducer may be called with undefined as the state value when the application is being initialized. If that happens, we need to provide an initial state value so the rest of the reducer code has something to work with. Reducers normally use ES6 default argument syntax to provide initial state: (state = initialState, action).

At the time of initial render, the state can be initialized with undefined. So, It's very important to initialize the state with your initial state.

Answer (score 0):

It's specifically a safety check in `combineReducers` to avoid accidentally *not* returning any state at all:

https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers#notes

> - It must never return `undefined`. It is too easy to do this by mistake via an early return statement, so `combineReducers` throws if you do that instead of letting the error manifest itself somewhere else.
> - If the `state` given to it is `undefined`, it must return the initial state for this specific reducer. According to the previous rule, the initial state must not be undefined either. It is handy to specify it with ES6 optional arguments syntax, but you can also explicitly check the first argument for being `undefined`.